# AG grid refuses to show rows when only a certain filter is applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have an AG Grid table that refuses to show rows but only when I filter by user name. This is the problematic column that I have throughout the application.

```
 {
            headerName: t.main('TABLE.HEADER.USER'),
            field: 'name',
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 150,
            filter: true,
            filterParams: {
                filterOptions: ['contains'],
                trimInput: true,
                debounceMs: 650,
                maxNumConditions: 0,
                suppressAndOrCondition: true,
            } as ITextFilterParams,
            cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams<IAuthenticatedUser>) => (
                <div className="u-display--flex u-display--flex--col">
                    <Link className="c-anchor--main u-type--sml" to={`${params.data?.userId}`}>
                        {params.data?.firstName + ' ' + (params.data?.lastName ?? '')}
                    </Link>
                    <small className="u-type--color--light-gray">{params.data?.email}</small>
                </div>
            ),
        },
```

What the change in the filter does is this (inside my wrapper component around AG Grid):

```
   const onFilterChanged = (params: FilterChangedEvent) => {
            const allFilters = params.api.getFilterModel();

            const queryParameters = [];

            for (const columnKey in allFilters) {
                if (allFilters.hasOwnProperty(columnKey)) {
                    const filter = allFilters[columnKey];

                    if (filter.filterType !== 'date') {
                        queryParameters.push(`${columnKey}=${filter.filter}`);
                    } else if (filter.filterType === 'date') {
                        queryParameters.push(`${helperService.camelToPascal(columnKey)}=${filter.dateFrom}`);
                    }
                }
            }

            const queryString = queryParameters.join('&');

            if (!withFrontEndPagination) {
                paginationStore.setSearchQuery(queryString);
            }
        };
```

At the bottom there, the setSearchQuery method is invoked which sets the search query in a mobx store, and when that query changes, this happens:

```
   const { loading } = useRequest(
        async () => {
             const response = await   userManagementService.getAllUsersPaginated(paginationStore.queryString);
                usersStore.setUsers(response.items);
                updatePagination(response);
        },
        [paginationStore.queryString],
        { disableGlobalLoading: true }
    );
```

And this is how I'm passing the rows to the grid:

```
<AGTable columns={columns} rows={usersStore.users} loading={loading} />
```

The problem that I'm having is that of all the filters in all the grids in my application, when I get the filtered data from the backend - and the data is there, I've tested it in all possible ways - the data is stored in the global mobx store, the ag component receives the data, the pagination shows that the data is there (e.g. I get "showing 5/36" as if the data were there), but the rows are simply not visible.

However, if I put a key on the grid component and force it to be re-rendered when the store data changes, only then do I see the rows (but that solution is unacceptable because I lose all the other filters applied to the grid).

I don't understand how this can be happening only when I filter by user name, the same approach works for 20+ different filters, and again, the data is definitely there in the store, just like when I use all those other filters (which is confirmed by pagination changes and the fact that if I apply a key to the component, it shows the filtered data).

EDIT: Including a normal table element to display the data shows that the data is there, and even including another AG Grid underneath the one in which the filter is applied, shows the correct filtered data - it is only in the grid where the filter is applied that the data doesn't appear (but it doesn't show an empty state, the pagination still works, except you're scrolling through empty pages). Also, to reiterate, it is only when I apply filters that are somehow related to user data (for whatever bizarre reason).

Another thing I've noticed is that for a split second when I remove the filter, the row data appears and then I see the unfiltered data (the unfiltered data is always shown).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resolved after banging my head against the wall for the last 24 hours. The solution was...  change  filterOptions: ['contains'], to  filterOptions: ['notContains'] even though I'm filtering by 'contains' rather than 'notContains'... Who knows what the real problem is or was, but maybe this manages to help someone one day lol.